# How to refactor a series of functions in a promise to a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, promise

How do I refactor this code using a for loop:

```js
const [userA, userB, userC, userD] = await Promise.all([
    createTestUser(),
    createTestUser(),
    createTestUser(),
    createTestUser()
]);
```

Comment: A `for` loop wouldn't be the right approach here because it'd run sequentially - you need `Promise.all`. Is your desire to make the code less repetitive?

Comment: yes, I may have to change the number of test users I am going to want to create for tests. So I am looking for a way to be able to pass the number (eg. 4, 8, 10, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
const userPromises = [];
for (let i=0; i<4; i++) {
   userPromises.push(createTestUser());
}
const users = await Promise.all(userPromises);
// const [userA, userB, userC, userD] = users;
```

Or, a bit shorter:

```
const users = await Promise.all(Array.from({length: 4}, _ => createTestUser()));
```

Comment: You can eliminate the arrow function wrapper, and just pass `createTestUser` as second argument to `Array.from`.

Comment: @trincot I thought about that, but preferred to ensure that `createTestUser` is called with no arguments (instead of `undefined` and an index).